# Running processing code in canvas by getting the code from textarea

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js

I am trying to get the processing code from textbox and make it running in canvas but i don't know what is happening can someone help me? When i debug it's says ctx.compile(); is not a function how can i make it work propperly?  Here is the code i use.

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style2.css" >
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitTryit() {
        var text = document.getElementById("textareaCode").value;
        var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifr.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");
        document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);    
        var ifrw = (ifr.contentWindow) ? ifr.contentWindow : (ifr.contentDocument.document) ? ifr.contentDocument.document : ifr.contentDocument;
        ifrw.document.open();
        ifrw.document.write(text);  
        ifrw.document.close();
        canvas();     

        if (ifrw.document.body && !ifrw.document.body.isContentEditable) {
        ifrw.document.body.contentEditable = true;
        ifrw.document.body.contentEditable = false;

        }

    function canvas() {
        var ifrr = document.getElementById('iframeResult');
        var iframediv = (ifrr.contentWindow.document) ? ifrr.contentWindow.document : (ifrr.contentDocument.document) ? ifrr.contentDocument.document : ifrr.contentDocument;
        var canv = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        canv.setAttribute('id', 'mycanvas');
        var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
        ctx.compile();
        iframediv.body.appendChild(canv);
    } 
}
function compile(){
    var processingCode = document.getElementById('textCode').value;
    var jsCode = Processing.compile(processingCode).sourceCode;
}



</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<!--Iframe-->
 <div class="iframecontainer">

    <div id="iframewrapper" class="iframewrapper">
    </div>

 </div>

<!--PJS text field-->
 <div class="PJStextwraper">
  <div class="overPJStext">
  </div>

    <textarea id="textCode" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" wrap="logical">   int x,y,w;
float vx,vy;

void setup() {
  size(300,200);
  x = int(random(width));
  y = int(random(height));
  vx = random(5);
  vy = random(5);
  w = int(10+random(10));
}

void draw() {
  background(140,70,60);
  ellipse(x,y,w,w);
  x += vx;
  y += vy;
  //
  if(x > width || x < 0) {
    vx *= -1;
  }
  if(y > height || y < 0) {
    vy *= -1;
  }
}

    </textarea>
 </div>

<button class="BT" type="button" onclick="submitTryit()">Run &raquo;</button>

</div> <!-- End container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if there are any errors??? Hit f12 to get at dev-tools and the console

Comment: I've tryed it give me exception:type error which tells:ctx.compile() is not a function. Itryed to do something like a var                                            com = compile();
ctx.com;                                                                                                         and code runs without errors but the canvas is not apear in the screen and console says that com is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "ctx.compile(); is not a function" is expected since you are trying to call a function that does not exist on the 2d canvas context. If I understand correctly, you are trying to run your own `compile` function and render it on the canvas you just created.

To do so, you need to change a few things, try the following and see if it works:

```
function canvas() {
    var ifrr = document.getElementById('iframeResult');
    var iframediv = (ifrr.contentWindow.document) ? ifrr.contentWindow.document : (ifrr.contentDocument.document) ? ifrr.contentDocument.document : ifrr.contentDocument;
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    canv.setAttribute('id', 'mycanvas');
    // The ctx will be created in an instance of Processing.
    // So no need for the following line.
    // var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    compile(canv);
    iframediv.body.appendChild(canv);
}

// Here you can pass the canvas where you want to render the code.
function compile(canv) {
    var processingCode = document.getElementById('textCode').value;
    var jsCode = Processing.compile(processingCode).sourceCode;
    // Now that you have the code in JS, you can create an instance of Processing.
    // But, what you get from the compiler is a string,
    // so you need to convert the string to JS.
    // For instance, I use here eval(jsCode) 
    var processingInstance = new Processing(canv, eval(jsCode));
}
```

Comment: Ups i shared a wrong code sorry for that i fixed that problem earlyer, thanks for help but that Error **iframediv.body is null** is still apear when i try to run code when i press the Run button. I know that i can't put anything in element which is not created on the document yhet, but if it was not on the document the value of iframediv would be undefined, isn't it? Although when i start debugging the code is running again how ti should be... i don't know what's hapenning. PS sorry for my bad explanation but i am new at programing.

Comment: Forget abouth it i find my mistake i just had to erase one line of code in my example of HTML page which i am written. Thanks for help.

Comment: If this was the answer you where looking for you can accept it ;)  - If not, please share your own solution for others to learn as well. Best of luck on your learning process!

Comment: i like your answer after i published the qestion i put other textarea (in the first function textareaCode) and i put in it like example very basic HTML code but because i wasn't shore i put a **src** to the Processing library in it and that was the problem of my Error after thateverything run just fine That is the code:

Comment: I do not know why but code don't wont to line corectly    
`<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
     <head>
        <script src="processing-1.4.1.js"></script><!-- i erase that line-->
     </head>
     <body>

     </body>
   </html>`